# cgywin64: make -f Makefile

Tags: makefile, cygwin, svm

I'm trying to use mpi-ikl-simplemkl-1.0 (http://www.mloss.org/software/view/174/)

I'm using Windows 8.1 and I've installed cgywin64. When I type (on cgywin bash screen):

```
make -f Makefile
```

The result is:

```
gcc-4.2 -03 -ffast-math -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC    -c -o svm.o svm.cpp
gcc-4.2: error: spawn: No such file or directory
makefile:32: recipe for target 'svm.o' failed
make: *** [svm.o] Error 1
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The internet wisdom seems to be that you should do one of:

- Remove /bin from PATH
- Remove /usr/bin from PATH
- Reinstall gcc (possibly remove all versions of gcc first)